# Why do widescreen monitors cost more than standard (4:3) monitors?

Tags: display, widescreen

...when standard monitors have more pixels and display area (for the same diagonal size)?  This has been so in the last few years and this is so now.

Comment: Please give examples.

Comment: Weird, to me a widescreen monitor *of equivalent **vertical** size* would have more pixels, hence **wide** -screen....

Comment: Comparing diagonal size is only relevant for devices that share the same aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because widescreen is more popular.
There are several reasons for this.

There's a prevailing idea that you can 'get more done' on a widescreen monitor.
You can fit more windows side by side on a 16:10 or 16:9 monitor than you can on a 4:3 monitor.  Because not everyone has the eyesight to be able to read tiny fonts and windows when using a 4:3 monitor at the native resolution, most people don't care as much about the number of pixels.

Widescreen monitors use the same 16:9 ratio as the widescreen DVD format.  Having a monitor that can display this format without the 'nasty black bars' makes having a 16:9 monitor, even with a lower resolution, attractive to the average buyer.

It costs a lot less to make a lower resolution monitor, yet they're perceived as a more advanced piece of technology, so they cost more.

It's like the iPhone and the iPod Touch.  The iPhone 4 retails at over $600 with no contract, yet the same equipment without a phone antenna retails for around $200.

Comment: Although some of what you say is true, none of it explains the price difference (in fact, the original poster's assertion that 4:3 monitors are cheaper isn't true)

Comment: Just answering the question to the best of my ability what has been asked.